# Cardgame, Why is one part of switch statement working but not the other?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

So I'm writing a little cardgame to learn some C#. Its my first project and I am having a little trouble. So the game just ask you a few simple questions. Is the next card red or black, is the next card higher or lower than the previous card, and the next card inside or outside the two previous cards. Finally, Pick a suit for the next card. Its all working except for the in out section. I'm using a switch statement to aquire the userinput and then if statements to kick out the correct answer. it runs perfectly if you switch on the "in" but incorrectly if you input "out" Please help. Furthermore, any critque would be nice. Thank you for your help.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace Drinking_Game_
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        Card card = new Card();
        Intro intro = new Intro();
        Game drink = new Game();
        deck.Shuffle();
        intro.intro();
        drink.game();
        //Console.WriteLine(deck.TakeCard());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


        //In out part of the  Game
        Card inOut = new Card();
        deck.Shuffle();
        inOut = deck.TakeCard();
        Start2:
        Console.WriteLine("Is the next card going to be inside, out, or equal to \n {0} & {1}
        (in, out or equal)  \n", rorbcard,highLow);
        string userValue2 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine(inOut.ToString());
        switch (userValue2)
        {
            case "out":
                          //+                      -
                    if (rorbcard.CardNumber > highLow.CardNumber)
                    {
                        if (inOut.CardNumber > rorbcard.CardNumber) & (inOut.CardNumber <
                        highLow.CardNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (rorbcard.CardNumber < highLow.CardNumber)
                    {
                        if (inOut.CardNumber < rorbcard.CardNumber) & (inOut.CardNumber >
                        highLow.CardNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                    }
                break;
            case "in":
                    if (rorbcard.CardNumber > highLow.CardNumber)
                    {
                        if (inOut.CardNumber < rorbcard.CardNumber & inOut.CardNumber >
                        highLow.CardNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (rorbcard.CardNumber < highLow.CardNumber)
                    {
                        if (inOut.CardNumber > rorbcard.CardNumber && inOut.CardNumber <
                         highLow.CardNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
                        }
                    }
                break;
            case "equal":

                    if (inOut.CardNumber == rorbcard.CardNumber || inOut.CardNumber ==
                    highLow.CardNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bold move, but wrong drink 6\n");
                    }
                break;
            default:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must input in, out, or equal");
                    goto Start2;
                }
        }
 public enum Suit
{
    Spades = 0,
    Hearts = 1,
    Diamonds = 2,
    Clubs = 3,
}

public enum CardNumber
{
    Two = 1,
    Three = 2,
    Four = 3,
    Five = 4,
    Six = 5,
    Seven = 6,
    Eight = 7,
    Nine = 8,
    Ten = 9,
    Jack = 10,
    Queen = 11,
    King = 12,
    Ace = 13,
}

public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardNumber CardNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CardNumber + " of " + Suit;
    }


}

public class Deck
{

    public Deck()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Cards = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(1, 13).Select(c => new
        Card()
        {
            Suit = (Suit)s,
            CardNumber = (CardNumber)c
        } )).ToList();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Cards = Cards.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid())
                     .ToList();
    }

    public Card TakeCard()
    {
        var card = Cards.FirstOrDefault();
        Cards.Remove(card);
        return card;


    }

    public IEnumerable<Card> TakeCards(int numberOfCards)
    {
        var cards = Cards.Take(numberOfCards);

        var takeCards = cards as Card[] ?? cards.ToArray();
        Cards.RemoveAll(takeCards.Contains);

        return takeCards;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Providing a very large dump of code and saying "it doesn't work, fix it" isn't how this site works.  What is the specific problem?  How *should* it work?  You should also limit the code you provide to the smallest sample that is capable of reproducing the problem, rather than dumping the whole thing.

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: For critiques of code, use codereview.stackexchange.com. For specific questions about your code, use this site. Reduce these hundreds of lines of code to a small case that clearly demonstrates the problem. By doing so either (1) you'll find the problem, or (2) you'll have a program that is small enough for someone else to find the problem quickly.

Comment: New at this sorry. Revised code to make smaller.  when you input "out" and the card is outside the two previous card it is still saying wrong

Comment: @EricLippert I will us use the codereview when I finsih this up thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is with your logic in determining whether a card is "outside" the range. Currently, your inner `if` statements basically say: "if the card is less than the smaller card **and** greater than the larger card", which is clearly not possible, instead you want to be asserting that the card is less than the smaller card **or** greater than the larger card, using the boolean OR (`||`) operator:

```
...
if (rorbcard.CardNumber > highLow.CardNumber)
{
    if (inOut.CardNumber > rorbcard.CardNumber) || (inOut.CardNumber < highLow.CardNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
    }
}
else if (rorbcard.CardNumber < highLow.CardNumber)
{
    if (inOut.CardNumber < rorbcard.CardNumber) || (inOut.CardNumber > highLow.CardNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct give 6 drinks\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong take 6 drinks\n");
    }
}
break;
...
```

Note that as others have mentioned, when both sides of the AND or OR are `bool` types you should be using the Conditional operators `&&` and `||`, rather than the Logical `&` and `|`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Its so obvious now I'm kicking myself.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed more parentheses in your out case. This may change de behaviour of your code.

Comment: The extra parentheses was me trying to fix the code. It did not work either way. The "in" does work.

Comment: Use && instead of & for the AND operator.